# The type of the quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

I have been doing the following exercise, and there is one line that I do not understand.

---

[image: part1]

---

I have solved a) and got

[image]

Regarding b) I realised that [image]

**Now** what I do not understand: After this it says in the solutions: I.e. after a rotation with

$$\begin{align}y_1&= x_1 + x_{2n}\\&\vdots\\ y_n &= x_n + x_{n+1}\\y_{n+1}& = x_1 − x_{2n}\\&\vdots\\ y_{2n}& = x_n − x_{n+1}\end{align}$$

we see that the quadratic form is indefinite, when it is written as:

[image]

**My question is** what does this part *after a rotation with...* mean? Thank you!

Comment: Just a linear change of variable in which the matrix ($A$ such that $y=Ax$) is orthogonal. But for proving that the quadratic form is not definite it is enough to know that it is a change of variable, actually. For some values of $y$ you get a negative value, for some you get a positive value. Since it is a change of variable (has an inverse) then there are corresponding values of $x$ that do the same.

Comment: Actually that change of variable is not a rotation. It is a rotation and a dilation. Look at the case of two variables to get a pictorial idea. If $x=a+b, y=a-b$, then the point $(a,b)=(1,0)$ is sent to $(x,y)=(1,1)$ and the point $(a,b)=(0,1)$ is send to $(x,y)=(1,-1)$. You see that there was a rotation by $\pi/4$ and an expansion by $\sqrt{2}$.